# How can I change the direction of a web page to RTL for Arabic, Hebrew?

Tags: javascript, css, right-to-left, direction

Could you please help me with changing the direction of [this page](https://github.com/Grible/timetable.js) to RTL? I have tried several solutions but unfortunately none of them works fine.

Comment: `[...]I have tried several solutions but unfortunately none of them works fine. [...]` and which solutions did you trie? It is important that you tell use those, otherwise will give you the most common ones which are moste likey the ones you tried.

Comment: I changed the web page direction to RTL but the content align is not right.
Here is a photo: bb.co/dkyThp
While the LTR direction is: ibb.co/j4qxa9
For example Sightseeing should be in ROTTERDAM from 09:00 to 11:30 but it shows something totally different in the RTL direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to fill the ticket at their [GitHub](https://github.com/Grible/timetable.js/issues) page, asking for adding support for such option naively.

For now, you could simply go with adding *CSS* rule:

```
.timetable aside,
.timetable section 
{
    float: right;
}
```

Besides, you should also learn more about [text direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) attribute, that indicates the directionality of the element's text.

Comment: I added the CSS rule you mentioned but still did not work. Even when I change the direction, I get wrong content. Here is a photo of the LTR direction: ibb.co/j4qxa9 but when I change the direction to  RTL, I get: ibb.co/dkyThp
For example Sightseeing should be in ROTTERDAM from 09:00 to 11:30 but it shows something totally different in the RTL direction.
I will fill a ticket at their GitHub page as you said. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can simply add some CSS:

```
.timetable{
    text-align: right;
}
.timetable aside
{
   float: right;
}
```

and in the div where you include the plugin:

```
<div class="timetable"  dir="rtl"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but the content is not right. Here is a photo of the LTR direction: ibb.co/j4qxa9 but when I change the direction RTL as you said, I get: ibb.co/dkyThp For example Sightseeing should be in ROTTERDAM from 09:00 to 11:30 but it shows something totally different in the RTL direction.

Comment: can you please try to do the following:
after: renderer.draw('.timetable'); 
setTimeout(function(){
var nodes = $('.room-timeline').children;
for(var i = 0; i <nodes.length; i++){
nodes [i].getElementsByTagName('a')[i].style.right = parseFloat(nodes [i].getElementsByTagName('a')[i].style.left) + 6 + '%';
}
}, 10)

Comment: I think there is something you did wrong, because it's working for me

Comment: Could you please send me the whole code as a zipped file?

Answer (score 0):

Some times this may be worked. Try and let me know.

Add `dir="rtl"` to your `html` tag

```
<html dir="rtl"></html>
```

or

Add `direction:rtl;` property to `html` tag styles in styles heet.

```
html { direction:rtl;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Waleed Ahmad, try my solution and let me know. thanks.

Comment: The content is not right.
Here is a photo of the LTR direction: https://ibb.co/j4qxa9 but when I change the direction RTL as you said, I get: https://ibb.co/dkyThp
For example Sightseeing should be in ROTTERDAM from 09:00 to 11:30 but it shows something totally different in the RTL direction.